# make <a> element fill his parent element

Tags: html, css, laravel

I'm trying to make my link element that I created with laravel fill the div element where it is in .

```
<li class="{{ Active::route('guide-dashboard') }}">
 <div class="dashboardLink">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o dashboardIcon"></i>
    {{ HTML::linkAction('GuideController@getIndex',  "Messages") }}
 </div>
</li>
```

normally you would put the div element in the 'a' tags but since this link is made with laravel I have no idea how to put things between the 'a' tags.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you can do it, one way is to set the `a` tag to a block element and with it full width/height

```
a{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

This approach avoids having to set a position style on the parent element. 
(as a `div` is already a block level element)

Please not though that this approach will be fine if you parent element contains no other content or elements **unless** they are also positioned absolutely. You'd need to use position styling on your elements if this is the case. (and watch out for z-index issues etc)

Comment: I chose the positioning because he's got the icon `<i>` to worry about as well.

Comment: Percentage values on `width`/`height` of (inline-)block elements only works if the value is set explicitly on the parent element as well.

Comment: @HashemQolami are you sure? this [fiddle suggests otherwise](http://jsfiddle.net/p7hzxt2x/).

Comment: @atmd Pretty sure! http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/p7hzxt2x/1/ As you can see, `height: 100%` is calculated to `auto` in this case. However I withdraw my comment about `width`.

Comment: right sorry yes I see what your saying. I guess I was assuming now other content in the div unless also absolutely positioned. will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

To fill, you'll need to specify a container size for the parent.  Something like this will work:

```
.dashboardLink
{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.dashboardLink a
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: @HashemQolami - 100% necessary.  By default, `<a>` is an inline element.  If he wants the entire box to be clickable, he needs to set either block or inline-block.

Comment: Absolutely wrong. The `a` element is being positioned `absolute`ly, hence the computed value of `display` would be `block`. This is true for all inline, inline-block, block, ... See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Comment: I'll give you that the display:bock is unnecessary.  Unfortunately, one of the side effects of having done this for so long is that we sometimes chase things which no longer apply in any practical sense.  Removed.

Answer (score 0):

It is more flexible to just use normal html tag but using **Larave Url helper** for generating path.

```
<a href="{{ action('GuideController@getIndex') }}">
   <i class="fa fa-envelope-o dashboardIcon"></i> Message
</a>
```

And if you named your route you use `route` function

```
<a href="{{ route('routeName', $params) }}">
   <i class="fa fa-envelope-o dashboardIcon"></i> Message
</a>
```

More information: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#urls